# Android:Null Pointer in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am making an app in which i am using ViewPAger and my code is working fine on S2 and NOTE but i checked on Y its giving exception on viewPagerAdapter. My code is as follows:

```
static PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
static ViewPager  mViewPager;
 static ViewPagerIndicator mIndicator;
 static String addposition;
public Context _context=this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create our custom adapter to supply pages to the viewpager.
  mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter); // **Null Pointer Exception**
```

Comment: and logcat as well that might be use full

Comment: Thanks hotveryspicy , your hint worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not write `public Context _context=this;` in global. You should initialize the content in onCreate().

**Edit**

Actually I had not seen that you are not using the context. I think there is an issue in the ViewPager. May be you are getting null object of ViewPager. If you show your xml then we can provide a better solution

Comment: But he is not using _context in the code that he has shown, so the problem is anything else.

Comment: Actully the problem was with xml only . Thanks for your support and +1 for that